# PFObject Subclass as a Property in another PFObject Subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, subclass, parse-platform

[[X-Post from parse.com]](https://parse.com/questions/pfobject-subclass-as-a-property-in-another-pfobject-subclass)

`Person` is a *subclass* of `PFObject`.

`Address` is also a *subclass* of `PFObject`. `Address` has a `@property` of type `Person`.

**i.e.**

```
// Person.h

@interface Person : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (retain) NSString *secondName;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@end

// Person.m

#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation PP4MEAddress
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic firstName;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Person";
}

// Address.h

@interface Address : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) Person *deliverToPerson;
@property (retain) NSString *line1;
@property (retain) NSString *line2;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

// Address.m
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation PP4MEAddress
@dynamic deliverToPerson;
@dynamic line1;
@dynamic line2;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Address";
}
```

Both *subclasses* are registered in the `App Delegate`.

In a method in `MyViewController` I want to set these as so

**e.g.**

```
-(void)myMethod
{

    Address *address = [Address object];
    address.deliverToPerson.firstName = @"John";
    address.deliverToPerson.secondName = @"Smith";
    address.line1 = @"123";
    address.line2 = @"Main Street";
    [address saveInBackground];

}
```

When this code executes, an entry of Class `Address` is input into the `Data Browser` on the Parse.com Web App. However, the only columns are `objectId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and `ACL`

I imagine this is because, under the hood the `Address @property` of type `Person` is not being `allocated` and `initialised`.

How do I overcome this?

Do I write a custom `setter` and `getter` for

```
@property (retain) Person *deliverToPerson;
```

in `Address.m` ?

If so, I notice that the `@property` is `atomic` and thus will I need to write locking code in said `setter` and `getter`?

Thank You

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MartinR. The reason I have not accepted it is that I was looking for a different approach, and an answer to question about the atomicity of the property. Initialising the Address properties in the controller, doesn't seem to me to follow MVC design. That's why I was looking at the idea of a custom setter / getter in Address that would alloc and init the Person object; if this is an incorrect approach an answer as to why it is. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with parse.com, but I strongly assume that you have to
allocate the `Person` object before setting the relationship. Something like

```
Address *address = [Address object];
address.line1 = @"123";
address.line2 = @"Main Street";

Person *person = [Person object];
person.firstName = @"John";
person.secondName = @"Smith";
address.deliverToPerson = person;

[address saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your PFobject 
like this

```
PFObject *anotherPlayer = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Player"];
    [anotherPlayer setObject:@"DataValue" forKey:@"Name"];
```